# Iterate Through Sent Items Folder -Error when hitting non-mail Item

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to iterate through all the mail messages in my Sent Items folder.

The code works fine until it hits a non mail item such as a calendar invitation.

Is there a way to skip over the calendar items in the sent items folder?

```
Sub Find_Sent_Messages_With_Subject()

    Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem


    Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)


    For Each myItem In myFolder.Items

        If InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") > 0 Then
            'Stop
        End If

    Next myItem

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
```

With

```
For i = myFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 '<- backwards        
    Set myItem = myFolder.Items(i)
    Debug.Print myItem
Next i
```

Or try adding `object.class` while looping through

```
    If myItem.Class = olMail Then
```

Example:

```
Dim myItem As Object

For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
    If myItem.Class = olMail Then
        Debug.Print myItem
    End If
Next myItem
```

**Edit**

*Tested outlook 2010*

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find_Sent_Messages_With_Subject()
    Dim myOlapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myOlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = myOlapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

    For Each myItem In myFolder.Items
        If myItem.Class = olMail Then
            If InStr(1, myItem.Subject, "hello") > 0 Then
                Debug.Print myItem
            End If
        End If
    Next myItem

End Sub
```